# How to use Maybe in higher order function haskell?

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I wanted to solve the below problem where f returns Nothing, then the first element is removed. If f returns Just x,  the first element is changed with x. My answer below works correctly for Nothing but I couldn't understand how to differentiate Nothing and Just inside the function

```
change:: (a -> Maybe a) -> [a] -> [a]
change f [] = []
change f (x:xs) = xs
```

change(\x -> Nothing) [1..5]          == [2..5]

change(\x -> Just 10) [1,2,3]          == [10,2,3]

Comment: You first have to decide what `f` will be called on. In general, it's not going to be a constant function like shown in your examples; the function will actually *use* its argument `x`, so you can only get a `Maybe` value by first calling `f`. You can't pattern match on the *function* itself.

Comment: If the first argument *is* intended to be a constant function, it's a bit odd why it doesn't just take a `Maybe a` value to begin with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for a simple solution you can just pattern-match (with `case`) on `f x` like this:

```hs
change:: (a -> Maybe a) -> [a] -> [a]
change _ [] = []
change f (x:xs) =
   case f x of
       Just x' -> x':xs
       Nothing -> xs
```

that should do what you described

---

for a shorter one you can use [`maybeToList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:maybeToList) and concat the parts like this:

```hs
change:: (a -> Maybe a) -> [a] -> [a]
change _ [] = []
change f (x:xs) = (maybeToList $ f x) ++ xs
```

Comment: You can avoid `maybeToList` and use `change f (x:xs) = maybe id (:) (f x) xs`. `maybe` does not need an import.

Comment: nice one too ;)

Comment: `change f = concatMap (maybeToList . f) = (>>= maybeToList . f)`. interestingly, `maybeToList` is the natural transformation from `Maybe` to `[]` (I think).